# Extract file name from a path using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I extract the string "XMLFileName" from the below URL using regular expression

```
var x = "C:\Documents and Settings\Dig\Desktop\XMLFileName.xml"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with `split()`, `pop()` and `replace()`...

```
var filename = x.split('\\').pop().replace(/\..+$/, '');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8uK6/).

You could also use a single regex...

```
var filename = x.replace(/.*\\|\..*$/g, '');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xdrX/).

Ensure you escape the `\` in your string literal too.

Comment: that will give you the extension as well.

Comment: Working like a charm :-) Very thanks. I am very poor in regular expressions that is why I have asked for help.

Comment: @32bitkid: Didn't notice that requirement, I'll make an edit.

Comment: @32bitkid I have expected an answer from you when I see a comment "oh common! really?" on Question :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use: "`[^\\]*$`"

but why not using regular javascript functions like `indexOf()` etc.

Comment: "`[^\\]$`" will match the very last character of the extension. He appears to not want the extension, and he does want more than one letter.

Comment: for the first problem you are correct it was a typo, and I fixed it, as for the second my bad I thought he needed the filename