# extract script name from URL

Tags: php, regex, url

I looking for regexp help how to extract just script name from url:

I have:

```
"http://www.example.com/index234.html"
```

and looking to receive `"index234"` ?

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426568/extract-file-name-from-a-path-using-regular-expression except you're dealing with forward slashes instead of back slashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [this](http://regexr.com?2vdra) regex:

```
/^http:\/\/(www\.)?example.com\/(?<scriptName>.*)\.html$/
```

**Edit:**

[this](http://regexr.com?2vdrg) regex would work for different urls and paths

```
/^http:\/\/(www\.)?(.*\/)*(?<scriptName>.*)\..*$/
```

Comment: not quite... I could be different site and path to script like: `http://www.difrentsite.org/folder/subfolder/newindex1.php` and and would need `newindex1`

Comment: I removed `www` part to be more robust and use `'/^http:\/\/?(.*\/)*(?<scriptName>.*)\..*$/'` - works perfect. +1 for `<scriptName>` - thank you

Answer (score 6):

Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/index234.html';
$parts = parse_url($url);
preg_match('~([^/]+)\..+$~', $parts['path'], $m);
print_r($m);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => index234.html
    [1] => index234
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try: `http://([\w\-\.]+/)+([\w\-\.]+)\.html`
the script name is in 2nd capture ($2 or \2). you can adjust the protocol and file extension as required, note that I don't really know what characters are actually allowed for url name, so in this case I assume letters, numbers, hyphens and dots only.